# How can a Turing Machine recognize a regular language?

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, simulation

This is a practice problem for a midterm in a class I'm taking:

> Given a regular language $L$, describe formally a Turing machine that recognize $L$.

I'm not sure how I should do that.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What other models do you know of that can accept regular languages, and how could you simulate them with a Turing Machine?

Comment: My ideal is since every regular language has a DFA..so, the problem is how Turing Machine simulates DFA? Am I right?

Comment: That's right. Now, a DFA consists of 5 parts: state-set, alphabet, initial-state, final-state-set and transition-function. What does a Turing Machine consist of, and which would correspond to each part of a DFA?

Comment: I solved it..really appreciated it..

Comment: @user67584 You should add your answer here, both for review and for later visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A DFA consists of 5 parts: state-set, alphabet, initial-state, final-state-set and transition-function. What does a Turing Machine consist of, and which would correspond to each part of a DFA?

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is regular and so accepting by a dfa. for each transition $\delta(p,a)=q$ in the dfa accepting $L$ let $\delta(p,a)=(q,a,R)$ for define a TM which accepting $L$.